# crear un reproductor básico con javazoom

Tags: java, javazoom

Verán, estoy haciendo un reproductor de musica pero lo mas simple que me he topado es con la librería basicplayer este puedo dar la información sobre la música la duración, pause etc... pero no sé como implementarlo en mi programa.
Normalmente la poca información que dan es sobre este método pero no sé cómo usarlo.

```
 public void progress(int bytesread, long microseconds, byte[] pcmdata, Map properties)
  {
    // Pay attention to properties. It depends on underlying JavaSound SPI
    // MP3SPI provides mp3.equalizer.
    display("progress : "+properties.toString());
  }
```

alguien me podría ayudar por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la propia página del plugin puedes encontrar un apartado con código de prueba.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Map;
/**
  * This class implements a simple player based on BasicPlayer.
  * BasicPlayer is a threaded class providing most features
  * of a music player. BasicPlayer works with underlying JavaSound 
  * SPIs to support multiple audio formats. Basically JavaSound supports
  * WAV, AU, AIFF audio formats. Add MP3 SPI and Vorbis
  * SPI in your CLASSPATH to play MP3 and Ogg Vorbis file.
  */
public class BasicPlayerTest implements BasicPlayerListener
{
  private PrintStream out = null;

  /**
   * Entry point.
   * @param args filename to play.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    BasicPlayerTest test = new BasicPlayerTest();
    test.play(args[0]); 
  }

    /**
     * Contructor.
     */
  public BasicPlayerTest()
     {
      out = System.out;
     }

  public void play(String filename)
     {
       // Instantiate BasicPlayer.
      BasicPlayer player = new BasicPlayer();
      // BasicPlayer is a BasicController.
      BasicController control = (BasicController) player;
      // Register BasicPlayerTest to BasicPlayerListener events.
      // It means that this object will be notified on BasicPlayer
      // events such as : opened(...), progress(...), stateUpdated(...)
      player.addBasicPlayerListener(this);

  try
     { 
      // Open file, or URL or Stream (shoutcast, icecast) to play.
      control.open(new File(filename));

      // control.open(new URL("http://yourshoutcastserver.com:8000"));

      // Start playback in a thread.
      control.play();

      // If you want to pause/resume/pause the played file then
      // write a Swing player and just call control.pause(),
      // control.resume() or control.stop(). 
      // Use control.seek(bytesToSkip) to seek file
      // (i.e. fast forward and rewind). seek feature will
      // work only if underlying JavaSound SPI implements
      // skip(...). True for MP3SPI and SUN SPI's
      // (WAVE, AU, AIFF).

      // Set Volume (0 to 1.0).
      control.setGain(0.85);
      // Set Pan (-1.0 to 1.0).
      control.setPan(0.0);
    }
    catch (BasicPlayerException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Open callback, stream is ready to play.
   *
   * properties map includes audio format dependant features such as
   * bitrate, duration, frequency, channels, number of frames, vbr flag, ... 
   *
   * @param stream could be File, URL or InputStream
   * @param properties audio stream properties.
   */
  public void opened(Object stream, Map properties)
  {
    // Pay attention to properties. It's useful to get duration, 
    // bitrate, channels, even tag such as ID3v2.
    display("opened : "+properties.toString()); 
  }

  /**
   * Progress callback while playing.
   * 
   * This method is called severals time per seconds while playing.
   * properties map includes audio format features such as
   * instant bitrate, microseconds position, current frame number, ... 
   * 
   * @param bytesread from encoded stream.
   * @param microseconds elapsed (<b>reseted after a seek !</b>).
   * @param pcmdata PCM samples.
   * @param properties audio stream parameters.
  */
  public void progress(int bytesread, long microseconds, byte[] pcmdata, Map properties)
  {
    // Pay attention to properties. It depends on underlying JavaSound SPI
    // MP3SPI provides mp3.equalizer.
    display("progress : "+properties.toString());
  }

  /**
   * Notification callback for basicplayer events such as opened, eom ...
   * 
   * @param event
   */
  public void stateUpdated(BasicPlayerEvent event)
  {
    // Notification of BasicPlayer states (opened, playing, end of media, ...)
    display("stateUpdated : "+event.toString());
  }

  /**
   * A handle to the BasicPlayer, plugins may control the player through
   * the controller (play, stop, ...)
   * @param controller : a handle to the player
   */ 
  public void setController(BasicController controller)
  {
    display("setController : "+controller);
  }

  public void display(String msg)
  {
    if (out != null) out.println(msg);
  }
}
```

Puedes leer toda la guía para desarrolladores en :
http://www.javazoom.net/jlgui/developerguide.html

Comment: oye muchas gracias ya pude hacer funcionar el metodo process pero ahora el problema es que solo me aparece ceros ala hora de imprimir el proceso,sabes como solucionarlo?

Comment: ya lo soluciones muchisimas, gracia llevo 3 semanas tratando de resolver mi duda. saludos.